# Webfonts not working in IE11

Tags: font-awesome, webfonts, glyphicons

I have developed an application that uses bootstrap glyphicons and font-awesome.  A major customer has tight security rules and the glyphicons are not displaying when using IE11.

The site is hosted in Azure.  At the customer's site they work in Chrome.  They also work in IE on a machine that runs it locally (with visual studio).  I think it's an 'Internet' zone setting but I don't have permission to see it.

I host the css and font's in my application.

When I go to the font-awesome site (http://fontawesome.io/icons/) I **cannot** see the fonts.

When I go to the bootstrap site (http://getbootstrap.com/components/) I **can** see the glyphicons.

I changed my app to use the CSS from bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css).  I can see that it downloads the css but I don't see the font.

When running locally, using the bootstrap hosted css, I see it successfully get's the font with this request.
http://getbootstrap.com/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?

When hitting my hosted site it never seems to attempt to get the font.  I don't see any errors.

Why can I not get the font in my application but it works on the bootstrap site?